# How to reorganize scraped data from messed tables with python?

Tags: python, html, dataframe, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrap data and reorganize it in a df. The problem is to select the information in the tables, since it is not a perfect table such as in the wikipedia models I trainned.

The information in this [site](https://www.tce.sp.gov.br/jurisprudencia/exibir?proc=18955/989/20&offset=0) should correspond as a row in the final product. The final result should be something like the organization on the
[image]

I had success scraping the data an selecting the tables using the following code, but them i got stuck. Could someone help me, please?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = requests.get("https://www.tce.sp.gov.br/jurisprudencia/exibir?proc=18955/989/20&offset=0")

soup = BeautifulSoup(html.content, 'html.parser')

info = soup.find("table", attrs={"class": "table"})

print(info)
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to iterate the second table and prepand all info from first on to the data - Choosed this solution, cause it is not clear if there can be multiple documents from same type, so it would not make sense to have something like link [typeA]1, link[typeA]2, ...:

*`walrus operator` is a new syntax that is only available in Python 3.8 and later.*

```
data = []

for e in soup.select('table:last-of-type tr:has(td)'):
    d = dict(zip(it:=iter(soup.table.stripped_strings),it))
    d.update({
        'link': e.a.get('href'),
        'date': e.select('td')[-2].text,
        'type': e.select('td')[-1].text
    })
    data.append(d)
```

or without `walrus operater`:

```
for e in soup.select('table:last-of-type tr:has(td)'):
    it = iter(soup.table.stripped_strings)
    d = dict(zip(it,it))
    d.update({
        'link': e.a.get('href'),
        'date': e.select('td')[-2].text,
        'type': e.select('td')[-1].text
    })
    data.append(d)
```

##### Example

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = requests.get("https://www.tce.sp.gov.br/jurisprudencia/exibir?proc=18955/989/20&offset=0")

soup = BeautifulSoup(html.content)

data = []

for e in soup.select('table:last-of-type tr:has(td)'):
    d = dict(zip(it:=iter(soup.table.stripped_strings),it))
    d.update({
        'link': e.a.get('href'),
        'date': e.select('td')[-2].text,
        'type': e.select('td')[-1].text
    })
    data.append(d)

pd.DataFrame(data)
```

##### Output

|  | N° Processo: | Autuação: | Parte 1: | Parte 2: | Matéria: | Exercício: | Objeto: | Relator: | link | date | type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 18955/989/20 | 31/07/2020 | ELVES SCIARRETTA CARREIRA | PREFEITURA MUNICIPAL DE BRODOWSKI | RECURSO ORDINARIO | 2020 | Recurso Ordinário Protocolado em anexo. | EDGARD CAMARGO RODRIGUES | https://www2.tce.sp.gov.br/arqs_juri/pdf/810443.pdf | 16/03/2021 | Despacho |
| 1 | 18955/989/20 | 31/07/2020 | ELVES SCIARRETTA CARREIRA | PREFEITURA MUNICIPAL DE BRODOWSKI | RECURSO ORDINARIO | 2020 | Recurso Ordinário Protocolado em anexo. | EDGARD CAMARGO RODRIGUES | https://www2.tce.sp.gov.br/arqs_juri/pdf/801385.pdf | 20/01/2021 | Relatório / Voto |
| 2 | 18955/989/20 | 31/07/2020 | ELVES SCIARRETTA CARREIRA | PREFEITURA MUNICIPAL DE BRODOWSKI | RECURSO ORDINARIO | 2020 | Recurso Ordinário Protocolado em anexo. | EDGARD CAMARGO RODRIGUES | https://www2.tce.sp.gov.br/arqs_juri/pdf/801414.pdf | 20/01/2021 | Acórdão |

Comment: Vielen Dank!! There is another doubt. I'm not sure of how many "Parte" I will find either, do you think I could limit it to two and then go to the next information?

Comment: HAppy to help - This would be predestined for [asking a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) with exact this focus - Hint: Check for key in created `dict` and drop what is not needed or do so in your `dataframe`

Comment: Thanks, I wil ask it. Im only having problem using the code, it returns syntax errors in the ":=" from "    d = dict(zip(it:=iter(soup.table.stripped_strings),it))
"

Comment: May update your python -> walrus operator `:=` is a new syntax that is only available in Python 3.8 and later.

Comment: Thank you for editing the answer without the ":=". I'm new to this an im using google colab. Now the problem is in "for e in soup.select('table:last-of-type tr:has(td)'):", it returns the error "NotImplementedError: Only the following pseudo-classes are implemented: nth-of-type."